# TortoiseGit: Start Commit Hook not executed if "Run for this repository" is checked

Tags: tortoisegit

I just started using Git with the **TortoiseGit 2.8.0.0** client on Windows 10 and was trying to set up some client-side hooks. I would like to set them up in a way so that they are automatically set when I or my colleagues clone the repo so I checked "Run for this repository".

I noticed that the `Start-commit` Hook isn't being executed in that case. `Pre-commit` and `Post-commit` seem to work as expected.

If I provide the working tree path and don't check "Run for this repository" all scripts also run as expected.

For testing I just set the same script for all 3 hooks to see if they are working.
My .`tgitconfig` looks like this:

```
[hook "startcommit"]
    cmdline = %root%\\ARM\\start_commit.bat
    wait = true
    show = false
[hook "postcommit"]
    cmdline = %root%\\ARM\\start_commit.bat
    wait = true
    show = false
[hook "precommit"]
    cmdline = %root%\\ARM\\start_commit.bat
    wait = true
    show = false
```

Can anyone explain this behaviour and how to fix it? am I missing something here?

Comment: Are the hooks correctly displayed in the settings dialog?

Comment: @MrTux yes they are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a reproducible bug which will be fixed with the next (preview) release (version >= 2.8.4 are fixed).

There is no workaround, but to define it with a repository path, too.

Comment: Thanks. It's nice to get a quick response from the devs themselves :) I would +1 but I don't have enough rep (yet)